# How do I change in an eclipse web project the WebContent folder to something different?

Tags: eclipse, ide

With the Galileo release it is finally possible to convert a normal Java project to a dynamic web project. Unfortunately it assumes that the Web stuff is located in a folder WebContent, which is not necessarily the case for an existing project. How can I change it? In MyEclipse it is quite easy, but with a stock eclipse I don't find such an option!

Comment: +1 both of the answers work for me, you should accept one of them.

Answer (score 56, accepted):

I am not sure what you meant by "a stock eclipse", but Helios allows this functionality in a very straight-forward way:

Right click your dynamic web project and open "Properties".

Find Deployment Assembly and you should be able to set context paths from there.

Comment: This is the easiest way to accomplish this in Helios and later releases. No need to edit files.

Comment: I only discovered this yesterday - d0h!

Answer (score 25):

I am not sure if there is UI for this or not, but you can edit file .settings/org.eclipse.wst.common.component, and change following line:

```
<wb-resource deploy-path="/" source-path="/WebContent"/>
```

Change `/WebContent` to your preferred directory. I use this for a several years now and encountered no problems with it.

Answer (score 15):

Go in the project properties and do like this example where I use the Maven webapp folder:

[image]

Comment: I think eclipse should be more easy to locate this feature.