# strange behavior by position of welcome page in maven dynamic web project

Tags: java, eclipse, jsp, maven, web.xml

I created a web project using maven using:

```
mvn archetype:generate -DgroupId=com.test -DartifactId=ioehr -DarchetypeArtifactId=maven-archetype-webapp -DinteractiveMode=false
```

then imported project in eclipse and modified the web.xml file to add welcome file entry as:

```
<web-app>
    <display-name>test</display-name>
    <welcome-file-list>
        <welcome-file>index.jsp</welcome-file>
    </welcome-file-list>
</web-app>
```

by default this was the project structure

```
--src
-----main
---------webapp
---------------WEB-INF
----------------------web.xml
---------------index.jsp
--WebContent
-----WEB-INF
------------lib
------------web.xml
-----pom.xml
```

And then try to run project on server. and it gave me exception as
**The requested resource (/test/) is not available.**

And when I moved index.jsp to WebContent folder it shows me the welcome page.

My question is , **Why I manually needed to move index.jsp in WebContent folder.
Why it didn't work in webapp folder**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Eclipse serves files out of the `WebContent` folder by default. When you moved `index.jsp` to `WebContent` Eclipse found it and served it back.

You can change the location of `WebContent` to point at your project content as described here: [How do I change in an eclipse web project the WebContent folder to something different?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1581683/how-do-i-change-in-an-eclipse-web-project-the-webcontent-folder-to-something-dif)