# Change WAR directory in Eclipse

Tags: war, google-plugin-eclipse

I am using the google-plugin-eclipse add-on and the latest gcloud code. I have the Java version installed. On the old plugin you could change the war directory but on the new one I cannot. I am using Grunt and Bower and inject several dependancies. In the past I had a "dev" directory that I would use grunt build on to minimize the number of files and the files themselves into the "war" directory. While developing locally - I would change the eclipse settings to use the "dev" directory and then before publish I would build and test the war directory and publish from there. Screenshots below of old and new plugin settings. Any ideas how to change so I don't have to play a folder rename game?

[Old Plugin Settings Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4KlWL.png)
[New Plugin Settings Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7A3Gu.jpg)

Comment: Could you please open an enhancement request on [Cloud Tools for Eclipse](https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/google-cloud-eclipse/issues/new)?

Answer (score 1):

The new [Cloud Tools for Eclipse](https://cloud.google.com/eclipse/) (CT4E) is based on the Eclipse Web Tools Project (WTP).  WTP uses a set of rules called the *deployment assembly* to assemble a set of source files and directories into a WAR.  WTP provides a [project properties page for changing the deployment assembly rules](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1581683/how-do-i-change-in-an-eclipse-web-project-the-webcontent-folder-to-something-dif).  You can have multiple source directories combined into the same location.

So you can adjust your project's deployment assembly to add your `war` directory and have its contents to be deployed into the WAR root.